# How can i prove 2 sets in a Metric Space are separated if they are open or closed

Tags: metric-spaces

It actually says:

a) If $A\cup B=\emptyset$ and both are open (or both closed) then they are separated.

b)If $A$ and $B$ are separated then:

i) If $A\cup B$ is open $\Rightarrow A$ and $B$  are open.

ii) If $A\cup B$ is closed $\Rightarrow A$ and $B$  are closed.

Comment: For a) do you mean to say $A\cap B=\emptyset$ instead? Because as it stands currently, $A\cup B=\emptyset$ implies that $A=B=\emptyset$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember that two sets are separated if neither has a point in the other's closure. So for $(a)$ we have:

- Suppose $A\cap B=\emptyset$, $A, B$ are open. Assume they're *not* separated - WLOG, we have $x\in A\cap \overline{B}$. Since $A$ is open, there's some small $\epsilon$ such that $B_\epsilon(x)\subseteq A$ - but since $x\in \overline{B}$, what can you say about $B_\epsilon(x)\cap B$? Do you see why this means $A\cap B\not=\emptyset$?
- Suppose $A\cap B=\emptyset$, $A, B$ are closed. Again, assume $x\in A\cap \overline{B}$ for a contradiction. Do you see why this means $x\in A\cap B$?

---

For $(b)$, we'll use similar arguments. First suppose $A\cup B$ is closed and $A$ is not closed. Let $x\in \overline{A}\setminus A$. Since $A\cup B$ is closed, this means $x\in B$ - contradicting the assumption that $A$ and $B$ are separated. Similarly, if $A\cup B$ is open and $A$ is not open, we can find some $x\in A$ with an open ball $B_\epsilon(x)$ disjoint from $A\setminus\{x\}$. Do you see how to use the assumption that $A\cup B$ is open to get a contradiction, now?

Comment: Thx for your fast answer. Sorry though, I'm spanish native speaker, what does WLOG means ?

Comment: @JoséOsorio "Without loss of generality." So in this case, for instance, it might be that $x\in A\cap\overline{B}$ or that $x\in \overline{A}\cap B$, but the point is that these two cases are equivalent in an appropriate sense.

Comment: Cristal clear now.

Comment: in (b) ..
why does $A\cup B$ is closed$\rightarrow$  $x\in B$

Comment: @JoséOsorio Well, by assumption $x\not\in A$ (since $x\in \overline{A}\setminus A$) . . .